# Longest Ramp better implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I think I managed to write some code that finds the longest ramp of an array `A` in `O(n)` time, but that uses `O(3n)` space (Given a list a ramp is defined is a sub-list where the element i <= i+1 for all i in the list). I'm wondering if first, this is actually `O(n)` and is there any way to decrease the space complexity?

```py
import numpy as np
from math import floor

def get_ramp(A):
    if len(A) <= 1:
        # left, right, longest
        return [A,A,A]
    
    mid = floor(len(A)/2)
    
    left = get_ramp(A[:mid])
    right = get_ramp(A[mid:])
    over = overlap(left[1], right[0])
    
    if len(over)> 0:
        left[0] = over if over[0] == left[0][0] else left[0]
        right[1] = over if over[-1] == right[1][-1] else right[1]
            
    longest = max([left[2],right[2], over],key=len)
    
    return[left[0], right[1], longest]

def overlap(left, right):
    if left[-1] <= right[0]:
        return np.concatenate((left, right))
    return []
```

The above implementation doesn't work in all cases, I believe this newer approach does work, but still the same question:

```py
def ram_3(A, s, f):
    if s > len(A) or f > len(A):
        return []
    if s == f:
        return [[s,f],[s,f],[s,f]]
    
    mid = floor((s+f)/2)
    left = ram_3(A,s,mid)
    right = ram_3(A,mid+1,f)
    j = [0,0]
    
    if left[1][1] == right[0][0]-1:
        if A[left[1][1]] <= A[right[0][0]]:
            j = [left[1][0],right[0][1]]
            
            if j[0] == left[0][0]:
                left[0][1] = j[1]
            if j[1] == right[1][1]:
                right[1][0] = j[0]
    
    b = j
    if (right[2][1] - right[2][0]) > (j[1]-j[0]):
        b = right[2]
    if (left[2][1] - left[2][1]) > (j[1]-j[0]):
        b = left[2]
    
    
    return(left[0],right[1],b)

def get_longest_ramp(A):
    best = ram_3(A, 0, len(A)-1)[2]
    return A[best[0]:best[1]+1]
```

Comment: that seems a tad overengineered for what is basically a for loop and a counter

Comment: @Eumel the idea was to make it as efficient as possible, using a divide and conquer approach.

Comment: It's not O(n) time. O(n) time and O(1) space is possible and simple. It's not even correct, try for example `print(get_ramp([4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,6,4,4,4,4,4]))` where it outputs `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]`.

Comment: @KellyBundy could you provide some more feedback?

Comment: what is the definition of `longest ramp`? Is it the longest strictly increasing sub array (all the element adjacent)?

Comment: @user1984 the longest ramp is the longest sub-list following the rules of a ramp that were given: for all elements in the sub-list i <= i+1 the longest ramp is the longest sub-list

Comment: @KellyBundy I know O(n) and O(1) space are possible but how are they possible in Divide and conquer?

Comment: I didn't mean with divide and conquer (with that I think I can do O(n) time and O(log n) space). Ah, I just saw that you apparently added what I had in mind, though I didn't fully read it yet. I think `np.concatenate` takes linear time, making your original solution only O(n log n). Using indexes should indeed fix the bug I pointed out (the `over[0] == left[0][0]` check having false positives and thereby connecting the streaks of 4s when it shouldn't) and make it O(n) time and O(log n) space).

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you. The question was from a paper I sat last year. I found it stupid that is specifically wanted divide and conquer and specifically in O(n), I thought it was particularly harsh, no one got the fully correct answer everyone managed O(NlogN). I have been racking my brain trying to get it to work for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had some time to do some comparisons^^

```
import numpy as np
from math import floor
from itertools import groupby

A = np.linspace(0,5,1000000)+ np.random.rand(1000000)

def get_ramp_short(A):
    longest_start = 0
    longest_length = 0
    current_start = 0
    current_length = 0
    last_value = 0
    for index, i in enumerate(A):
        if i>= last_value:
            current_length += 1
        else:
            if current_length > longest_length: 
                longest_length = current_length
                longest_start = current_start
            current_start = index
            current_length = 1
        last_value = i
    print(longest_start, longest_length)
    return 

def get_ramp_iter(A):
    seq = (A[1:]-A[:-1])>0
    pos, max_len, cum_pos = 0, 0, 0

    for k, g in groupby(seq):
        if k == 1:
            pat_size = len(list(g))
            pos, max_len = (pos, max_len) if pat_size < max_len else (cum_pos, pat_size)
            cum_pos += pat_size
        else:
            cum_pos += len(list(g))
    print(pos, max_len)

def get_ramp_np(A):
    seq = (A[1:]-A[:-1])>0
    idx_pairs = np.where(np.diff(np.hstack(([False],seq==1,[False]))))[0].reshape(-1,2)
    start_longest_seq = idx_pairs[np.diff(idx_pairs,axis=1).argmax()]
    print(start_longest_seq[0], start_longest_seq[1]-start_longest_seq[0])
```

Results as follows:

```
%%timeit
print(get_ramp(A)) #yours
4.29 s ± 262 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
get_ramp_short(A) #vanilla python
215 ms ± 17.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
get_ramp_iter(A) #using itertools
3.44 s ± 341 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
get_ramp_np(A) #using numpy
13.7 ms ± 167 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can see your approach is beaten easily even though its (persumably) O(n) just like the other, how come? Function calls in python are pretty expensive, the way you tried it using recursion has a ton of those so while the complexity is equal a lot more processing time is spent.

The fastes way (i could find) for any long long arrays is as usual numpy whichs saves some extra time thanks to vectorization.

Comment: How is theirs O(n)? Doesn't `np.concatenate` take linear time? (A test of mine suggests it does, but I don't have the newest NumPy version...)

Comment: @KellyBundy Im pretty sure it is. I tried with 10x the values and it took ~10x the time so empiric testing agrees with me ;)

Comment: With what data? Like the `A` in your answer (which is pretty much a best-case input) or with sorted data (to elicit the linearithmic time)? Also, O(n) is rather hard to distinguish from O(n log n) with a benchmark, especially if the nlogn-part has a much lower hidden constant than the n-share like it does here. Again, what about `np.concatenate`? Does it take linear time or not? If it does, we have T(n)=2T(n/2)+cn, so not O(n) but O(n log n).

Comment: @KellyBundy the linspace in A is actually really small so A is basicallly full random with an ever so slight tendency upwards (i intended for it to be bigger but couldnt be bothered to change it). If you want to know how OP got to his complexity of O(n) i would suggest asking him ;) Afaik concatenate creates a new array and copys all values over which would make it O(n)

Comment: So you now agree that the OP's original code isn't O(n)?

Comment: @KellyBundy i neither agree or disagree, i wrote this as a comparison based on the assumption that OP was right

Comment: Hmm, that's not what your answer says. It instead *asserts* that the OP is right.

Comment: @KellyBundy ok you got me there. I looked like O(n), he said its O(n) so i acted like its O(n). If you want to discuss the O(n)ness of OPs approach i still suggest you take it up with OP

Comment: Well, they say they "think" they managed to do O(n), and their main (or at least "first") question is whether it actually is.